# Why are classLoader magic values in defineClass() throwing an exception?

Tags: java, runtime-error, classloader, custom-attributes, custom-component

I want to write a classLoader that can help me implement customized classes and ultimately a whole component at run time. Right now I'm in process of loading the class.

I'm trying to load this role.java file. However when I get to this part of the code:

```
myClass = super.defineClass(className, classData, 0, classData.length);
```

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value **1885430635** in class file C:\Users\ARIFAH\Downloads\Compressed\eUML2 free version\with classLoader code\2\archetypedComponentWithNull\src\aC\Role/java

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at customCL.customClassLoader.loadClass(customClassLoader.java:116)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at customCL.customClassLoader.main(customClassLoader.java:145)
```

I've read posts saying "you need something like OSGi". That would be similar to working on something new from scratch, which I'd like to avoid.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually loading a real class file. The magic value of any valid class file is `0xCAFEBABE`, and this magic in hex is `0x7061636B`.

Notice that if we convert `0x7061636B` to ASCII byte by byte, it turns out to be the string "pack". This means that the file you think is a class file actually starts with the string "pack".

Comment: okey, so i guess i was trying to load package instead of a class. thanx

Comment: +1. Note that `*.java` files usually begin with `package` declarations. I bet (s)he was trying to load Java source code rather than a compiled class. ([(S)he wouldn't be alone.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15857422/978917))